# How to get tours that a user booked in reverse order of booking?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
TourSchema = {name, otherFields}
UserSchema = {name, otherFields}
BookingSchema = {tour (id of tour), user (id of user), createdAt, otherFields}
```

In my BookingSchema I have a pre middleware hook:

```
bookingSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
  this.populate('user').populate({
    path: 'tour',
    select: 'name'
  });
  next();
});
```

Because of this hook, in my controller this doesn't work anymore:

```
const bookings = await Booking.find({ user: req.user.id }).populate('tour').sort({
    createdAt: -1
  });
```

Currently i am able to retrieve booked tours of a user by this code:

```
  const bookings = await Booking.find({ user: req.user.id }));

  const tourIDs = bookings.map(el => el.tour._id);
  const tours = await Tour.find({ _id: { $in: tourIDs } });

  res.status(200).render('overview', {
    title: 'My Tours',
    tours
  });
```

But the order in not descending, I want to retrieve tours according to revese order of booking. reveresing based on BookingSchema->createdAt.

Answer (score 0):

Use .sort() method on Booking collection,

```
const bookings = await Booking.find({ user: req.user.id }).sort({createdAt:-1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `.sort()` to be applied (intended) on `BookingSchema` model before the population of tours.

```
await Booking.find({ user: req.user.id })
  .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
  .populate({
    path: "tour",
    select: "name -_id" //selecting only name of tour in population
  })
  .exec();
```